# How do you use Autofac to inject setters into your action filters in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, autofac

I thought this would do the trick in my Global.asax Application_Start, but it doesn't work:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InjectActionInvoker();
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

User error - turns out I miss-configured my container. The above code does indeed setup setter injection for action filters.